# Query to find customers that have deposit in all branches located in a specific city

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query

I have 3 tables as follow:

```
Customer (CustomerName , CustomerCity , CustomerStreet)
Branch   (BranchName , BranchCity)
Deposit  (CustomerName , BranchName , AccountNumber , Balance)
```

Here I show you sample data of the above tables :

```
Customer ('John','City1','Street1')
         ('Lili','City2','street2')

Branch   ('Branch1','Kaj')
         ('Branch2','Bahar')
         ('Branch3','Bahar')
         ('Branch4','Bahar')

Deposit  ('John','Branch1',12,1000)
         ('Lili','Branch1',123,1222)
         ('Lili','Branch2',124,45233)
         ('Lili','Branch3',345,6000)
         ('Lili','Branch4',567,5600)
```

So based on the information above, I need a query to give me CustomerName
that have a deposit in *all* branches that are in Bahar.

I should see 'Lili' in the output because it has deposits for all branches that are in Bahar but I should not see John cause it has a deposit only in one branch of Bahar.

I did my best to write the query but I could not. Could you help me with this please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have two solutions for your question :
solution 1 , I use `Not Exists , Except`

```
Select distinct C.CustomerName
From customers C
where NOT EXISTS ((Select BranchName
                   From Branch
                   Where BranchCity='Bahar')

                      EXCEPT

                   (Select BranchName
                    From Deposit a
                    where A.CustomerName = C.CustomerName))
```

In solution 2 I use `Not Exists ,`

```
Select Distinct C.CustomerName
From Customers C
Where NOT EXISTS  (Select BranchName
                   From Branch b
                   Where BranchCity='Bahar'
                   and NOT EXISTS (select BranchName
                                   from Deposit a
                                   where a.CustomerName=C.CustomerName
                                   and a.BranchName=b.branchName))
```

Each one of the query above will answer your query and give you the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

```
select CustomerName
from Deposit
group by CustomerName
having count(distinct BranchName) = (select count(*) from Branch)
```

Note that **distinct** is only used if there are multiple deposits by the same customer and branch.
However, it's possible to use join with *Customer* table or nested lookup queries for more information.

Answer (score 1):

```
;with cte as(
  select c.Name as Cname,b.Name as bName,
  ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by c.Name order by b.Name,c.Name) RowID
  from Customer c 
  inner join Deposit d on c.Name=d.CustomerName
  inner join Branch b on b.Name=d.Branch
  where b.City='Bahar'
)
select Cname from cte 
group by cName
having max(RowID)=(select count(*) from Branch where City='Bahar')
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT c.CustomerName
FROM Customer c
CROSS JOIN Branch b
LEFT JOIN Deposit d
ON d.CustomerName = c.CustomerName
AND d.BranchName = b.BranchName
WHERE b.BranchCity = 'Bahar'
GROUP BY c.CustomerName
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN d.AccountNumber IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```